# Coding 2 28BYJ-48 5V DC (motor) with a LJ12A3-4-Z/AX (sensor)

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I coded everything and everything is working properly
    I'm trying to make a true/false statement were the motors spin clockwise or anti-clockwise depending on what the sensor reads, I'm getting this error when I try to make a(n) if/else statement.
   In other words, I'm trying to do it make boolean = 0 according to what the sensor senses (if it senses something = 1 if it doesn't =0). The end of the code is the important part, but I had to post all the code so that you'd know the "int's".

```
int Pin1 = 10;
int Pin2 = 11;
int Pin3 = 12;
int Pin4 = 13; 
int _step = 0;
int Pin5 = 9;
int Pin6 = 8;
int Pin7 = 7;
int Pin8 = 6; 
int _stip= 5;
int sensor = 3;
boolean dir = HIGH;//LOW=clockwise, HIGH=counter clockise 
void setup()
{
  pinMode(Pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensor, INPUT);
}

  void loop ()
  {
    switch (_step){
      case 0:
      digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin4, HIGH);
      break;
      case 1:
      digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin4, HIGH);
      break;
      case 2:
      digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
      break;
      case 3:
      digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
      break;
      case 4:
      digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
      break;
      case 5:
      digitalWrite(Pin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
      break;
      case 6:
      digitalWrite(Pin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
      break; 
      default:
      digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
      break;
    }
      if(dir){
        _step++; 
        }else{
          _step--;
        }
          if(_step>7){
            _step=0;
          }
            if(_step<0){
              _step=7;
              }
              delay(1);
               switch (_step){
      case 0:
      digitalWrite(Pin5, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin7, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin8, HIGH);
      break;
      case 1:
      digitalWrite(Pin5, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin7, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin8, HIGH);
      break;
      case 2:
      digitalWrite(Pin5, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin7, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin8, LOW);
      break;
      case 3:
      digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
      break;
      case 4:
      digitalWrite(Pin5, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin6, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin7, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin8, LOW);
      break;
      case 5:
      digitalWrite(Pin5, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin6, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin7, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin8, LOW);
      break;
      case 6:
      digitalWrite(Pin5, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Pin6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin7, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin8, LOW);
      break; 
      default:
      digitalWrite(Pin5, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin6, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin7, LOW);
      digitalWrite(Pin8, LOW);
      break;
    }
      if(dir){
        _stip++; 
        }else{
          _stip--;
        }
          if(_stip>7){
            _stip=0;
          }
            if(_step<0){
              _stip=7;
              }
              delay(1);

  if (digitalRead(sensor) == HIGH){
    digitalWrite(dir,HIGH);
  }
  else{
  digitalWrite(dir,LOW);

  }
  }
```

Comment: What is *this error* ? I've read it a few times and I'm not sure. The code at the end looks ok semantically. but hard to tell.

Comment: Your pin sequences are weird, six time 1,2,3,4; but twice 1,4,3,4. That seems suspicious. Similarily 7 times 5,6,7,8; once 1,2,3,4.

Comment: Using identifiers which start with `_` is not recommended.

Comment: Your HIGH/LOW sequences confuse me. I keep looking for the HLLH for step 7, but it is not in your code; it will hence use the all LOW default.

Comment: Now that I am done ranting about your code without even understanding it; what is actually your question? You mention an error, but as lakeweb already mentioned, you do not elaborate. Please explain more about what happens unexpectedly. What should happen but does not? If you get compiler errors or warnings please quote them, in full, verbatim and as text directly here (i.e. not as picture of text). Does your motor misbehave? I mean apart from the stuttering which I consider unavoidable with sequences like yours.

Comment: This looks suspicious `if(_step<0){_stip=7;}`. I do not trust this mixture of `_stip` and `_step`. Please explain what the difference between the two variables and their semantic is. Is it possible that you introduced `_stip` by accidental typo and have then written random  code to make the compiler shut up about it being not defined? I bet you could remove all `_stip`, consistently work with `_step` and thereby get rid of several problems.

Comment: Hi Ziad. I see you have been around recently. Please comment on how I can make my answer more helpful, maybe even participate in cooperating on solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I decided to start an interactive answer, because commenting simply does not cut it here.
In the first step, I will just fix everything about your code which triggers doubt in me.
Then I invite you to comment and explain which of my changes are unclear to you or whether there are any you actively reject.

Voters, I know this is not yet an actual answer, I am following something like the compromise described here:
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)
I.e. as long as OP shows some effort and communication I am willing to lead them along.
If that does not work, I will delete this answer in frustration anyway.
So, if possible, please grant me some time while I try to get some cooperation running here.

Below is an edited version of your code, please let me know which of my changes you cannot accept. Please note that the changes I made a free of actually understanding your code, just based on experience-honed reflexes.
In case I have not by accident fixed your problem (wouldn't that be laughable?), please describe in detail that said problem. Then we can try to fix it.

```
int Pin1 = 10;
int Pin2 = 11;
int Pin3 = 12;
int Pin4 = 13; 
int current_step = 0; /* no prefix "_" */
int Pin5 = 9;
int Pin6 = 8;
int Pin7 = 7;
int Pin8 = 6; 
/* int _stip= 5; I just do not belive in this... */
int sensor = 3;
int dir = 1; //0=clockwise, 1=counter clockwise 
/* maybe boolean is type in your environment, maybe not; 
    and I do not trust HIGH/LOW to be boolean */
void setup()
{
    pinMode(Pin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Pin2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Pin3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Pin4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Pin5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Pin6, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Pin7, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Pin8, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(sensor, INPUT);
}

void loop ()
{
    switch (current_step)
    {
    case 0:
        digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW); /* 2, not 4 */
        digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin4, HIGH);
        break;
    case 1:
        digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin4, HIGH);
        break;
    case 2:
        digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
        break;
    case 3:
        digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
        break;
    case 4:
        digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
        break;
    case 5:
        digitalWrite(Pin1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
        break;
    case 6:
        digitalWrite(Pin1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
        break; 
    case 7: /* 7 is one of the allowed values, do not count from 0 to "oops" */
        digitalWrite(Pin1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin4, HIGH); /* HLLH was missing to close the loop */
        break; 
    default:
        digitalWrite(Pin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin2, LOW); /* 2, not 4 */
        digitalWrite(Pin3, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin4, LOW);
        break;
    }
    if(dir)
    {
        current_step++; 
    } else
    {
        current_step--;
    }
    if(current_step>7)
    {
        current_step=0;
    }
    if(current_step<0)
    {
        current_step=7;
    }
    delay(1); /* I don't think this delay is really necessary... */
    switch (current_step)
    {
    case 0:
        digitalWrite(Pin5, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin6, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin7, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin8, HIGH);
        break;
    case 1:
        digitalWrite(Pin5, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin6, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin7, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin8, HIGH);
        break;
    case 2:
        digitalWrite(Pin5, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin6, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin7, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin8, LOW);
        break;
    case 3:
        digitalWrite(Pin5, LOW);  /* 1,2,3,4 ? Seriously? */
        digitalWrite(Pin6, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin7, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin8, LOW);
        break;
    case 4:
        digitalWrite(Pin5, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin6, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin7, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin8, LOW);
        break;
    case 5:
        digitalWrite(Pin5, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin6, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin7, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin8, LOW);
        break;
    case 6:
        digitalWrite(Pin5, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin6, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin7, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin8, LOW);
        break; 
    case 7: /* poor 7, forgotten again */
        digitalWrite(Pin5, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Pin6, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin7, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin8, HIGH); /* closing the loop with HLLH */
        break; 
    default:
        digitalWrite(Pin5, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin6, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin7, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Pin8, LOW);
        break;
    }
    delay(1);

    if (digitalRead(sensor) == HIGH)
    {
        dir=1; /* dir is a variable, not a port */
    } else
    {
        dir=0;
    }
}
```